# ¿Como unir dos consultas en MYSQL, en una misma fila?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla cliente, la cual separa dichos clientes entre semanales, y diarios, la ayuda que necesito es en una sola consulta que me muestre el numero de clientes semanales, y el numero de clientes diario.

La consulta que he hecho me une los datos en dos filas la de esta forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que me la arroje de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo lograr unir los resultados en una misma fila?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta a su pregunta es el uso de `subconsultas`. SQL permite el calculo de un valor de una columna del conjunto de salida con base en una expresión de consulta que en tiempo de ejecución se calcule, para todas las filas del conjunto de resultados, a un único valor (a lo sumo una fila y exactamente una columna) el cual puede resolverse a un valor escalar o (si la subconsulta no da filas a null)

Un ejemplo que ilustra esta caracteristica puede ser el siguiente, el cual se ejecuta bien en MYSQL

```
select (select 1) as uno
      ,(select 2) as dos
```

el cual da como resultado

```
uno dos
--- ---
1   2
```

juntando el resultado de dos consultas, que en este ámbito se denominan `subconsultas` en una misma fila

Para la respuesta de su caso particular le debería funcionar lo siguiente en MYSQL

```
select (select count(*) from `cliente` where tipo_cliente = 'diario'),
       (select count(*) from `cliente` where tipo_cliente = 'semanal')
```

Ahora bien, la restricción de que, para todas las filas del conjunto de resultados el resultado (valga la redundancia) de la subconsulta se calcule a lo sumo en una unica columna con a lo sump una fila parte del hecho de que se intenta obtenerlo como un unico valor de columna para una fila

Comment: Hermano Muchas Gracias, con esta orientación di solución de inmediato